# Can i make a linq expression optional parameter in c# 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, optional-parameters

I have the following code.

```
public void GetMessages(Expression<Func<IMessageQueryable, bool>> messageSpecification, string folder = "INBOX")
{
    // Implementation stripped           
}
```

How can i provide default value for `messageSpecification`?. Specification says the value must be a compile time constant. Is this possible?.

EDIT: Not lookig for specifying it as `Expression<Func<IMessageQueryable, bool>> messageSpecification = null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bother? Create an overload for the same method without messageSpecification parameter and define it's default value yourself inside the overloaded method and pass it to your original method. Default parameters are actually never meant to be used like that anyway.

```
public void GetMessages(string folder = "INBOX")
{
    this.GetMessages(DEFAULT_VALUE, folder);        
}
```

Comment: so you mean my code is smelly and i am going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Definitelly, optional parameters were designed to [facilitate COM object interactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), not to be used like that. Downsides of optional parameters are discussed in dept in many forums.

Comment: Understanding how to OverLoad and OverRide methods is the beauty

Answer (score 2):

You can OverLoad it.  What would your default value be?